# Use EF4 DbContext with Domain Service

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I built my data access layer with the new code first stuff from Entity Framework 4, with a class derived from DbContext and various DbSet members.

Now I'm expanding to Silverlight and want to use WCF RIA services to access the DB.  Do I have to start over with ADO.NET Entity Data Models, or is there some way to use what I've got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't have to start over.  You can create a domain service and not inherit from anything.  Look at examples of how people use WCF RIA services with Nhibernate.

Here is some stuff about using RIA with ctp4.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/57793bec-abc6-4520-ac1d-a63e40239aed
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/0e741f7f-700f-4efd-b10c-98f050f76c85

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't search "EF code first RIA" before.  I'll give it a quick go then come back to accept your answer.

Comment: Please vote: http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services/suggestions/1579271-ef-dbcontext-code-first-domainservicedescription

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party but for people still looking for this, like I was earlier, take a look at this NuGet package.

http://nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.EntityFramework

It provides a `DbDomainService<>` base class similar to the `LinqToEntitiesDomainService<>`.